# Laplace Inverse transform in octave/Matlab transformation F(s)=1

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a problem. 
I want to transform the inverse Laplace of F(s)=1.
I do these steps:

```
>> syms s t
>> F=1
F =  1
>> ilaplace(F)
error: 'ilaplace' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

i can't understand the error.

Comment: octave does not seem to understand ilaplace. likely worng installation of the symbolic toolbox, id say

Comment: @AnderBiguri, i had done some other laplace transforms and they worked. I don't know about this one.. the result should be δ(t) ( dirac(t) ) .

Comment: The error says ilaplace undefined. Do you have a file called ilaplace maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this:

```
>> ilaplace(F,t)
ans = (sym) DiracDelta(t)
```